# How do I calculate the partial area under a curve with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, area

I am a newbie to matlab and trying to find the area under the curve (AUC) for a part of the graph not the entire graph. I am interested to calculate  separate AUC from 2 regions; one from -350 to -100 and other from -100 to +150 present on the x axis. how can I calculate AUC for these portion of the graph (not for entire x-axis)? not enough reputation to provide the figure. If someone from the community can provide a matlab code.

Every couple of values in the data set correspond to x,y coordinates. If plotted, these points generate individual (x,y) curve, where x is a fixed column from -750 to +750.
y data has N rows, something like

```
x = [-750:25:750];

y1 = [1.52,0.47,0.59,0.62,1.88,...];    
y2 = [1.5,0.79,0.74,1.46,0.6,...];  
y3 = [1.6,0.11,0.79,0.77,1.33,...];

yn = [0.061,0.0609,0.05948,0.0624,0.067,0.073347639,...];
```

...full data set not provided.

I want to calculate AUC for -350 to -100 region and from -100 to +150 region present on the x axis, for each combination of (x,y), say (x,y1), (x,y2)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (using `trapz`):

```
startingIndex = find(x==-350);
endingIndex = find(x==-100);

desiredX = x(startingIndex:endingIndex);
desiredY = y1(startingIndex:endingIndex);
area = trapz(desiredX,desiredY);
```

As found on http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/278102

basically it finds the index of the end points in the `x` array and then calcs the area under the curve from the corresponding truncated `y` vector.

Comment: one suppl. question...How can I fill the partial area between desiredX and desiredY after plotting X,Y plot(x,y)??

Comment: @Ashutosh `area(desiredX, desiredY)` perhaps? I'd have to try but I suppose that should work.

Comment: If your image gets overwritten execute `plot on` first, then plot stuff (curve and area) and finally execute `hold off`.

Comment: Yes I obviously meant hold on instead of plot on (typo). You are welcome btw

Comment: Sorry, for bothering you again, Is it possible to write **for loop** for calculating **desiredY**, I am having large no. of Y data from y1 to y300.

Comment: I don't understand, you mean several curves? Anyway, just create a new question if you have additional questions. Something like: "I learned how to calculate partial area but I would like to apply it to several functions. I tried this: ... How can I achieve this?". If you think the answer is too simple for a question then I'm sure you can come up with it yourself (google "for loop matlab").

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. I want to only calculate the area for each desiredY. as in your solution desiredY changes with y value. like from y1 to y300. I am trying to write a for loop code to change y value every time. This is what I tried 'startingIndex = find(x==-350);
endingIndex = find(x==-100);

desiredX = x(startingIndex:endingIndex);

for i = 1:300 

desiredY(i) = data [i] (startingIndex:endingIndex);
area = trapz(desiredX,desiredY);'

Comment: Merge the `y`'s into a matrix and loop over the rows, performing the given solution in each step.