# How can I implement for-loop to calcuate partial area of the curve in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have large data set in excel file having 100 rows and 300 columns. The first row is name of the variable from (y1:y300), rest of the data is numeric. I was interested to calculate partial AUC present between 2 fixed points of x axis.
I could do so using @ShellFish solution [How do I calculate the partial area under a curve with MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494578/how-do-i-calculate-the-partial-area-under-a-curve-with-matlab/30494655#30494655). Now I want to implement a loop which can calculate partial area for every y value say from y1 to y300. how can I use for-loop to achieve this? I used this code..I imported the .xls file using MATLAB import function.

```
    data = importfile('test.xls','Sheet1','A2:AZ100');
    y1 = data(:,1);
    y2 = data(:,2);
    y3 = data(:,3);
    y4 = data(:,4);
    y5 = data(:,5);
...
x = [-1000:10:1000];

startingIndex = find(x==-350);
endingIndex = find(x==-100);

desiredX = x(startingIndex:endingIndex);
desiredY = y1(startingIndex:endingIndex);
area = trapz(desiredX,desiredY);
area
```

My try for for-loop to calculate desiredY every time is

```
for i=y1:y100
    desiredY = i(startingIndex:endingIndex);
    area = trapz(desiredX,desiredY);
    area
end
```

but some thing is terribly wrong with my code..not working.

It would be great, if someone could help me correct this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong here. First, you can't define the iterators for a `for` loop like that. Second, there's no reason to explicitly define `y1, y2, ..., yn`, you can address the `data` array directly. My fingers hurt just thinking about typing all of that out :(

Using the linked question for some sample data and code:

```
% Set up sample data
data = rand(100,3);
x = 0:100;

startingIndex = find(x == 20);
endingIndex = find(x == 80);
desiredX = x(startingIndex:endingIndex);

% Preallocate
[nrows, ncolumns] = size(data);
desiredY = zeros(ncolumns, 1);
area = zeros(ncolumns, 1);

for ii = 1:ncolumns
    desiredY = data(startingIndex:endingIndex, ii);
    area(ii) = trapz(desiredX, desiredY);
end
```

This goes through every column of `data` and performs the linked integration, storing the result in `area`. Each index of `area` corresponds to the column in `y`.